# checking for inputted value if numbers or letters using test

Tags: jquery

```js
$('input').on("input", function() {
  if (isWhole($(this).val())) {
    return false;
    //$(this).removeAttr("style").removeClass("not");
  } else {
    //$(this).css("border", "2px solid red").addClass("not");

  }
});


function isWhole(n) {
  return /^\d+$/.test(n);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="" type="text" id="" />
```

In this OP i want to make user input only numbers. if they input letters it should not be allowed meaning it should not be written in the input.

1. I used test to test if inputted data is number.
2. When I comment return false when i input letters border is added. If i input numbers border is removed this is my desired out come.
3. Tried it with return false alone. I am assuming it will not let the inputted letter to show but it is still showing.
4. How to not let user input letters

Comment: Can you use `<input type='number'>` saves you all the hassle of an additional check using js. http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/tutorials/whats-new-in-html5-forms-handling-numeric-inputs-using-the-number-and-range-input-types.html#fbid=w1ah_NK1kue

Comment: @ClydeLobo i dont like the updown keys in the input using number type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test the value and if a number allow it - or in this case, allow the number part of it

```js
$('input').on("input", function(e) {
  var val = this.value;
  if (!isWhole(val)) {
    var num = parseInt(val);
    $(this).val(isNaN(num)?"":num);
  }
});


function isWhole(n) {
  return /^\d+$/.test(n);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="" type="text" id="" />
```

Comment: question why didnt my code work ?

Comment: because you are not stopping anything with return false

Comment: i need 4 mins to tick :)

Comment: i like it...................

Answer (score 1):

Simply replace any non-numeric symbol to empty string:

```js
$('input').on("input", function(e) {
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^\d]/, ''));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" />
```

Comment: question why didnt my code work ?